# $y'=-y-6x^2-12x, y(0)=0$ Find $y_1(x),y_2(x) , y_n(x)$ by Picard–Lindelöf theorem with the initial function $y_0\equiv0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=-y-6x^2-12x, y(0)=0$

Find $y_1(x),y_2(x) , y_n(x)$ by Picard–Lindelöf theorem with the initial function $y_0\equiv0.$

$y_1(x)=0+\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t,y_0(t))dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t,0)dt=\int_{0}^{x}-6t^2-12t=-2x^3-6x^2.$

$y_2(x)=0+\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t,y_1(t))dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t,-2t^3-6t^2)dt=\int_{0}^{x}(-(-2t^3-6t^2)-6t^2-12t)dt = \int_{0}^{x}(2t^3-12t)dt =$

$= \frac{2x^4}{4}-6x^2$

How I supposed to find $y_n(x)$ ? I cant see it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to calculate more values : $ y_3$ and $ y_4$....

Looks like the formula for $y_n$  is:
$$y_n(x)=12(-1)^n\dfrac  {x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}-6x^2$$